# Adding Preloader on Animate CC

Tags: javascript, adobe, preloadjs, animate-cc

I'm new in Adobe Animate. Is there a way for adding a preloader for loading image assets when creating a Canvas in Adobe Animate CC? Is it the same way as inserting the loadqueue class on the html file after the Animate CC has published the html and js?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you create two manifests to load - one with assets for preloader and the other with the rest of the assets.
First you load assets needed for preloader, add the preloader on stage and then you start loading the rest of assets and change the preload indicator on "progress" event.

One way to do this is to create 2 projects in Animate CC inside one folder (let's call them *preloader.fla* and *content.fla*). When you publish you will get a js file and html file for each project and a shared folders for images and sounds.
What you have to do next is open the html file created for *preloader* and paste some code from *content.html*, which includes importing the js file and loading the manifest.
If you do it all right, opening the preloader.html will first load the preloader, then add it to stage, load the rest of assets (while indicating progress) and add the next screen when it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

Preloaders support for HTML5 canvas has been added in the 15.2 released version of Animate CC. It lets you choose and set a GIF file as preloader and all the handling is taken care of automatically.

See here for details: 
https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/whats-new.html#preloader

https://helpx.adobe.com/content/help/en/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html#main-pars_header_1987795350